# finding two nums squared in array that equals input squared

Tags: c

I'm building a program in C using visual studio where i know the a defined array with array length of 8. My code however prints out very strange results and i cannot track the error down. Anyway here is the code. I appreciate any suggestions!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    int arraylist[] = { 4, 7, -4, 3, 8, 2, 9, -3,};
    printf("Enter a number to compare to the array ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("X is %d\n", x);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 8; j++)
        {
            int firstnum = arraylist[i] * arraylist[i];
            int secondnum = arraylist[j] * arraylist[j];
            int total = firstnum + secondnum;
            printf("%d", &total);
            if (firstnum + secondnum == x*x)
            {
                printf("%d", &i);
                printf("%d", &j);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("False");
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

if i set 16 as x, it prints out numerous lines of numbers and false like which doesnt meet the argument.

OUTPUT == 32 65 32 25 80 20 97 25 65 98 65 57 113 53 130 and so on for another 30 or so numbers. Any idea where i went wrong there?

Comment: Print statements such as  printf("%d", &j) print the address of the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printf` just gets passed the variables you want to print, not their addresses, so:

```
        printf("%d ", total); /* not &total */
        if (firstnum + secondnum == x*x)
        {
            printf("[ %d ", i); /* not &i */
            printf("%d ]\n", j); /* not &j */
        }
        else
        {
            printf("False\n");
        }
```

I've also added some spaces and square brackets and `\n` so the printed numbers don't run into each other and you can see the results.

You can combine the two `printf` of `i` and `j` like this:

```
            printf("[ %d %d ]\n", i, j);
```

Also (I don't know whether this is intentional - I assume not), you have an extra comma in your array initialisation of `arraylist[]` which means there's a final 0 on the end, and you are using this in your `for` loop - it should count to `<=7` not `<=8` if you want 8 items starting with 0.

Here is your programme marginally altered as per the above:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int
main (void)
{
  int x;
  int arraylist[] = { 4, 7, -4, 3, 8, 2, 9, -3 };
  printf ("Enter a number to compare to the array ");
  scanf ("%d", &x);
  printf ("X is %d\n", x);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
    {
      int j;
      for (j = 0; j <= 7; j++)
        {
          int firstnum = arraylist[i] * arraylist[i];
          int secondnum = arraylist[j] * arraylist[j];
          int total = firstnum + secondnum;
          printf ("%d ", total);
          if (firstnum + secondnum == x * x)
            {
              printf ("[%d ", i);
              printf ("%d] ", j);
            }
          else
            {
              printf ("False ");
            }
          printf ("\n");
        }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
Enter a number to compare to the array 3
X is 3
32 False
65 False
32 False
25 False
80 False
20 False
97 False
25 False
65 False
98 False
65 False
58 False
113 False
53 False
130 False
58 False
32 False
65 False
32 False
25 False
80 False
20 False
97 False
25 False
25 False
58 False
25 False
18 False
73 False
13 False
90 False
18 False
80 False
113 False
80 False
73 False
128 False
68 False
145 False
73 False
20 False
53 False
20 False
13 False
68 False
8 False
85 False
13 False
97 False
130 False
97 False
90 False
145 False
85 False
162 False
90 False
25 False
58 False
25 False
18 False
73 False
13 False
90 False
18 False
```

Those might seem like wild output, but those are indeed the sums of the various squares. For instance, it starts 32 = 4^2 + 4^2, 65 = 4^2 + 7^2, 32 = 4^2 + (-4)^2 etc.

Comment: oh ok yeah i see what you are saying, but my output still is all over the place with extremely large amounts of numbers. i added a sample run in the original post if you could take a look, i appreciate you help!

Comment: Your code as presented does not even print a space as in your sample problem. Please fix the `&` problem in `printf`, and update both the code and the output to what you actually see.

Comment: What you are getting is broadly correct. I've added a fixed version of the program and explained why the output is (broadly) correct.

Answer (score 0):

An array of N entries can be accessed with indexes between 0 and N-1.

In your case, you have an array of 8 entries, and you are attempting to access it with indexes between 0-8 instead of 0-7.

In short, change `<= 8` to `< 8`.

And In order to make it generic for any given size, use `sizeof(arraylist)/sizeof(*arraylist)` instead of 8.

Also, you are printing the addresses of variables `i`, `j` and `total` instead of their values.

So you need to get rid of the `&`.

Comment: He has an array of 9 elements, so `<= 8` is right. Note the final `,` in `int arraylist[] = { 4, 7, -4, 3, 8, 2, 9, -3,};` - that will set the last element to 0.

Comment: I pretty doubted that, so I tried `printf("%d\n",sizeof(arraylist)/sizeof(*arraylist))` and the result was 8!!!